# Add meta field after post has been published

Tags: actions, save-post, the-events-calendar

I'm trying to add a custom field of event_month when a post is published or saved.  I'm using the save_post action and getting the contents of a custom field containing the date and trying to store this in a separate custom field with just the month.  This works perfectly when saving a post that has already been created.  I've shown my code below.

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_event_date');

function update_event_date($post_id){

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $event_datee = get_post_meta($post_id, '_EventStartDate', true);

    if ($post_type == 'tribe_events'){

        $month = date("m",strtotime($event_datee));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'event_month', $month);

    }

}
```

The problem arises when creating a new post.  I think this is because the action fires before the `_EventStartDate` meta has been created and therefore the month can't be taken from this.

The hook is firing correctly and as intended when saving/updating a post but doesn't correctly get the month from the meta when creating a new post.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could provide me with some guidance.

Comment: `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom post type save\_post action not firing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75605/custom-post-type-save-post-action-not-firing)

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem... From my understanding, it seems like you try to get a post meta from a post that has not been created yet... Therefore, that would be normal you don't get its meta? Or your problem is it that you don't get the **meta box** in the posts you're creating? Or is that it doesn't **save** the meta box value when you're creating a new post?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into [`post_updated`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated) action, if you want to access the post's data *after* it's been published. This hook passes the post's ID, inundated post object, and updated post object.

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'update_event_date', 10, 3 );
function update_event_date( $post_id, $post_after, $post_before ){

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $event_datee = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_EventStartDate', true );

    if ( $post_type == 'tribe_events' ) {

        $month = date( "m",strtotime( $event_datee ) );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event_month', $month );

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. I found a solution before I read this using $_POST to grab the value I needed, but I'll be sure to try this method again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pre_post_update` instead of `save_post`

Full explanation [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91185/126253)

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. It works perfectly when saving or updating a post, but when creating a new event. It just sets the event_date as 01, rather than the actual month of the event.  However, when I then hit update post, it sets the event_month correctly

Comment: Check if your `pre_post_update` hook fires first. For example, put global $post->ID to any rewritable file on your filesystem.